# Smooth damp or tween algorithm

Tags: algorithm, lua

I would like to know an algorithm for smooth damp or as some people call it, tween. I would like it in Lua preferably but anything will help.

I have tried watching unity tutorials but can't transfer the code without a algorithm to substitute for the smooth damp function.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you're looking for an easing function. There is a Lua library that provides a set of easing functions on GitHub: https://github.com/EmmanuelOga/easing

An example would be:

```
local function inOutQuad(t, b, c, d)
  t = t / d * 2
  if t < 1 then
    return c / 2 * pow(t, 2) + b
  else
    return -c / 2 * ((t - 1) * (t - 3) - 1) + b
  end
end
```

Where t = time, b = begin value, c = change in value, and d = duration.

More information on these easing functions is available directly from Robert Penner here (this is where the function above is derived from): http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/

Comment: Thank You, I meant like I'm making an fps and need an algorithm for smooth sway. It may work.

Comment: I don't know how much information you're looking for. I was assuming you know how to interpolate between two values over a period of time, and you were just looking for a suitable smoothing function. If you need more info, let me know.

Comment: Figured out an algorithm in my head it works better then I was even thinking. Thank you for your time and help though.